# ember-data: How to tell if a model's async: true relationship is loaded without triggering a load?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to check if an async relationship has been loaded without triggering the load, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official way to accomplish this yet, but unofficially you can do

```
// this will be null if not loaded, and populated if it has at least started loading
if(model._relationships.yourRelationshipName) {...}
```

Answer (score 7):

After time has passed, Ember Data 2.5 got [released](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html). One of implemented features is the `ds-references` feature.

The references API allows to interact with your relationships. With it, it is possible to check if your `RelationshipName` is already loaded, without triggering a request:

```
model.hasMany('yourRelationshipName').value() !== null;
```

Answer (score 5):

With ember-data 1.13, the following will work for a `hasMany` relationship. Still a hack, but there does not seem to be a public API.

```
var relationships = model._internalModel._relationships.initializedRelationships;

if (relationships.yourRelationshipName.manyArray.get('isLoaded')) {...}
```

Comment: This is the only method that works for me, using Ember-Data 1.13.5. Note, for some reason, `relationships.myRelationshipName` sometimes was undefined for me until the array was loaded, so I had to do `if (relationships.myRelationshipName && relationships.myRelationshipName.manyArray.get('isLoaded'))`

Comment: Also, better yet, I've been playing up with this in Ember Data 2.12.1, and I ended up settling for this variant instead: `Ember.get(relationships 'relationshipName.hasLoaded')`. I found that the thing with the `_manyArray` told me the relationship was not loaded in cases where it was actually loaded from the server, but it had not been accessed so far via `model.get('relationshipName')`.

Answer (score 1):

update. Still not in public API =(

For now I use this:

```
s._data.yourRelationshipName.get('isLoaded')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this cause `model._relationships.yourRelationshipName` didn't work for me

`model._data.yourRelationshipName` did work tho will also be null if not loaded, and populated if it has at least started loading

Answer (score 0):

For a `hasMany` relationship the non-public API for accessing this in Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.12 is `model._relationships.tasks.manyArray.get('isLoaded')`