# Ember-data get "belongsTo" attr (id) from model without resolving the actual object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I want to get a models attribute (id) "belongsTo" without forcing a server call or resolving the object. I got memberships having a user. The most users are loaded and so I only want to make a server call for some of the users.
I updated recently to ember-data 1.13.4 and my old version is't working anymore.

Memberships:

```
user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: false }),
```

Until now I did this to check if a users was already in the store:

```
if (this.store.peekRecord('user', parseInt(membership._internalModel._data.user)) === null)
      return false;
```

But with the new Ember-Data update the _data does not include anymore the belongsTo - Ids.

Ends up in this on progress:

```
Error while processing route: workgroups Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'user' relationship on a 'membership' with id 21 but some of the associated records were not loaded.
```

I really really appreciate every help on this.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Based on this answer:

[ember-data: How to tell if a model's async: true relationship is loaded without triggering a load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365950/ember-data-how-to-tell-if-a-models-async-true-relationship-is-loaded-without/31177805#31177805)

I was able to figure it out for ember-data 1.13.4
Solution:

```
membership._internalModel._relationships.initializedRelationships.user.canonicalState.id
```

This is ugly. Any better ideas?

EDIT:
This can be used to extend the DS.Model with a function:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default {
  name: 'model-getid',
  initialize: function() {
    DS.Model.reopen({
      getId: function(key) {
        // TODO(sn): support hasMany as well
        const rel = this._internalModel._relationships.initializedRelationships;
        return rel && rel[key] && rel[key].canonicalState && rel[key].canonicalState.id;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

now it's possible to us it like this on single relation:

```
membership.getId('organisation')
```